# Uncaught ReferenceError: BookingData is not defined - where "BookingData" is Name of Collecton In Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
<form class="modal-content" id="bookingForm">
    <div class="formContainer">
      <h1>Booking Form</h1>
      <p>Please fill in this form to Book The Trip.</p>
      <hr>
      <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required id="email">


      <label><b>Package</b></label>

      <input type="text" id="packageFields" name="teste2">

      <label for="psw"><b>Name</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" required id="name">

      <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Phone No.</b></label>
      <input type="tel" placeholder="Enter Phone No." name="psw-repeat" required id="phone">

      <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Date Of Journey</b></label>
      <input type="date" placeholder="Enter Phone No." name="psw-repeat" required id="date">

      <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

      <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Confirm Booking</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('bookingForm').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
    </section>
    <!-- animation -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script>
    AOS.init();

    var modal = document.getElementById('bookingForm');
// Script To Copy Package Name To The Form Automatically
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function setPackage(packageName) {
  document.querySelector('#packageFields').value = packageName;
}
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->

 <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
 <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-app.js"></script>

 <!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
 <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

 <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
 <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
 <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
 <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
 <script src="bookingSubmit.js">    </script>
```

This Is The Html And The JavaSript Is Given Below:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "AIzaSyDT80mEpNS4CpdByl2ugrSTGzgQpkbzzeI",
   authDomain: "himwhitecab.firebaseapp.com",
   databaseURL: "https://himwhitecab.firebaseio.com",
   projectId: "himwhitecab",
   storageBucket: "himwhitecab.appspot.com",
   messagingSenderId: "505950138314",
   appId: "1:505950138314:web:c37c1b2c593f30e911e933",
   measurementId: "G-ECR97G3YY0"
 };

//reference messages collection


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var firestore =  firebase.firestore();

const submitBtn = document.querySelector("#signupbtn");


let email = document.querySelector('#email');
let packageFields = document.querySelector('#packageFields');
let name = document.querySelector('#name');
let phone = document.querySelector('#phone');
let date = document.querySelector('#date');

const db = firestore.collection(BookingData);

submitBtn.addEventListner('click', function(){
  let userEmailInput = email.value;
  let userPackageInput = packageFields.value;
  let userNameInput = name.value;
  let userPhoneInput = phone.value;
  let userDateInput = date.value;

  db.doc()
  .set({
    email:userEmailInput,
    package:userPackageInput,
    name:userNameInput,
    phone:userPhoneInput,
    date:userDateInput
  })
  .then(function(){
    console.log("Data Saved");
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

I am using this to store the data of my contact forms in my Firebase.

But It Gives The Error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: BookingData is not defined
>       at bookingSubmit.js:27

Where "BookingData" is the name of the collection in my firebase.

What Is The Cause Of The Error And How To Solve It...??

Please Check If Anything Else Is Wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "BookingData" is the name of your collection, then you will need to put it in quotes:

```
const db = firestore.collection("BookingData");
```

What you have now is trying to use a variable called `BookingData`, which hasn't been defined.  That's what the error message is trying to tell you.